# Convert TextField value to Int

Tags: java, eclipse, int

I have a TextField where I can type values; And I need to convert the value typed to Int and display it with S.O.Println.

```
EDIT:
```

I've tried now :

```
try {
int i = Integer.parseInt(myText.getText());
System.out.println("This is an integer " + i);              
}
catch (NumberFormatException x) {
System.out.println("Error : "+ x.getMessage());
}
```

But it's giving me :

```
This is an integer 122                // When I type 122
Error : For input string: "122,5"     // When I type 122,5
Error : For input string: "122.5"     // When I type 122.5
```

Any ideas.

**`EDIT:`**

This is it :

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(myText.getText());
int i = (int)d;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are using a comma as a separator, rather than a point. And anyway, you wouldn't be able to parse it as `int`. You'd need `Double.parseDouble(..)`

Use can use `NumberFormat` corresponding to the current locale in order to parse the input.

If you are using SWT (tagged eclipse) - I think you can limit the possible characters by adding a `VerifyListener` to the text field. In your listener, call `doit()` on the passed event if the input is allowed.

If using AWT (`TextField` being awt's text component) - then see [something like this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0226.html)

Answer (score 0):

You try to parse string "11,5" as integer. It is definitely not integer. Therefore the exception is thrown.

You can try to use Double.parseDouble() and the result depends on your Locale. If you are in English locale it expects dot (.) and not coma, so the number anyway should look like 11.5

Answer (score 0):

The comma is giving you a parse error. If you require the comma, you can use it as a delimiter and parse the two sides separately.

Here is an example of separating two comma separated values in a string.

```
String str = "1,2,3,4";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
     System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

The output would be:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

`11,5` is not a number that Java can parse without other interaction. You can replace the comma with a decimal point, along with removing any spaces (depending on your locale):

```
Double.parseDouble(myText.getText().replaceAll(",", ".").replaceAll(" ", ""));
```

Notes:

You cannot use the comma as a thousands separator.

Answer (score -1):

That's because the `myText.getText()` is `11,5` (not numeric) and not `11.5` (double).

Try doing,

```
Double.parseDouble(myText.getText().replaceAll(",", "."));
```

This replaces `,` to `.`.

Alternatively, uses `NumberFormat` to do your number conversion.

---

Also, I've noticed you're using `Integer.parseInt()` when parsing `double` numbers. That's why you're having exceptions thrown.

You should use `NumberFormat.getInstance(locale).parse(myText.getText())` to get your required result. Don't forget that `parse()` returns a `Number` object, so to get a double, do this:

```
double d = NumberFormat.getInstance(locale).parse(myText.getText()).doubleValue();
```

Comment: This is probably due to a difference in locale. Your solution would be dangerous in an application that needs to deal with localization, as it's not unusual for a comma to represent a thousands separator in some countries. This should be handled using NumberFormat.

Comment: problem with locale, the compiler can't understand locale !

Comment: You can use the `NumberFormat.getInstance()` or `NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())` (`locale` in my example = `Locale.getDefault()`).